# What happens to lifeless react components?

Tags: reactjs

I am right now implementing some kind of notification bubble for users of my webpage.

This bubble usually receives a set amount of time which it is 'alive', as in displayed, until it fades out.

When researching on how to do this fading out, I was usually just trying to figure out how to "remove" a component completely. However, it turns out that this is not the preferred way. The actual solution is to simply manipulate its state so it doesn't render anymore.

At this point I was seriously scratching my head. As I am usually working with languages like C++ or C# I immediately thought what the implications might be, but I didn't find anything.

What does actually happen to components which are in a 'lifeless' state? I mean, they still have to exist, right? Isn't this just polluting memory like crazy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean something like `this.state.isBubbleActive && <MyBubbleComponent />`? The `MyBubbleComponent` will be cleaned up and unmounted when it is no longer in use.

Comment: @Tholle should make this an answer. Also if you want to see the life cycle you can simply add something a componentWillUnmount function to see it happening

Comment: @Tholle So, what defines a component to be "no longer in use"? Creating an unfulfillable render condition?

Comment: @Sossenbinder What is returned from a component's render method will be diffed to what was returned in the last render, and any components that are no longer in use [will be unmounted](http://jsbin.com/deruceboba/1/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: @Tholle Thanks, that was some good piece of information! So if the diff resolves to the render condition going from "possible" to "impossible" the unmount method is called? This is simplified, I know, but that is how I imagine it to be right now.

Comment: @Sossenbinder I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. React will get a "[`React.createElement` tree](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgfAUABHYBZAngYQPYFsAOGB2ApvgC5wD0UcMw540QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)" back from the `render`, and will create/remove/update anything that differs.

Comment: @Tholle So if the render method of my component returns 'null' for example, React decides to unmount this component?

Comment: @Sossenbinder I think [this piece of the documentation is a great read](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

Comment: Look at the [JSBin in my previous comment](http://jsbin.com/deruceboba/1/edit?js,console,output). Returning `null` from a component will not unmount the component itself, but anything the component previously rendered will be unmounted, i.e. `MyComponent` in the example.

Comment: @Tholle I think I start to understand. I will give this a read immediately. It seems like I still have a long way to go to understand React completely! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sossenbinder also, to animate the exit behaviour, use packages like react-transition-group or react-move.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use [React's Lifecycle Methods](https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1) to unmount the notification bubble after a set amount of time.

It will be better optimized than having it in a "lifeless state" and only rendering on state or props update.

**Edit**: This doesn't answer the OP's question and is better served as a comment, I'll be leaving it up until they receive a more appropriate answer